# default language in web sites form

Tags: html, internationalization, webforms

How I can change default writing language in a website form ( html form or . . .)

I would like to change default language from english to persian

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you show some code? Do you mean the form's character set?

Comment: I want when a user want type any character in a textbox in form,only persian character accepted